How to implement Register and login in Azure AD B2C using Custom UI and APIs
How to implement Register and Login in Azure AD B2C using Custom UI and APIs and without using User flows.
Instead of redirecting to the Microsoft domain and authenticating the user on the custom UI defined in Azure, we want to call the the Azure AD B2C APIs from our UI.
We need this kind of implementation because the Registration and Login flow is not a page in the application, but an overlay which can appear on top of any page.
How can we call the Azure AD B2C from our UI app.
The UI app is a ReactJS based (NextJS) application.

You can't.
B2C is the same as ADFS and Entra ID - there is no "native auth" endpoint.
You have to use the Microsoft login screen.
The later product, viz. Entra External ID (now GA) allows native authentication.
